# Magento2 Order by clause in collection

Tags: magento2, collection, edit-order

I have a custom collection to which I add filters. For example, I have this:

```
$giftColletion = $this->_giftFactory->getCollection();
$giftColletion->addFieldToFilter('store_id', 1);
```

What filter should I add to $giftColletion so it can return all the records  by field **position** in ASC order ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can try this

```
$giftColletion = $this->_giftFactory->getCollection();
$giftColletion->addFieldToFilter('store_id', 1);
$giftColletion->setOrder('position','ASC');
```

`setOrder` is use for sorting

Answer (score 2):

According to `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection` you can use `addAttributeToSort()` method to sort your collection.

This has worked for me:

```
$collection = $this->_collection
    ->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(['sku', 'name', 'image'])
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->addAttributeToSort('name')
    ->setPageSize($limit);
return $collection;
```

Use whatever attribute you need your collection to be sorted by instead of `'name'` in my example. 
You can also specify order direction as the second parameter, it defaults to `ASC`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$page = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('p')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
$pageSize = 10;
$allMagazines = $this->MagazineFactory->create()->getCollection();
$allMagazines->addFieldToFilter('is_enable', 1);
$allMagazines->setOrder('sort_order','ASC');
$allMagazines->setPageSize($pageSize);
$allMagazines->setCurPage($page);
return $allMagazines;
```